# How to have a table that updates across multiple sheets in both directions in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have two sheets, and a table that I want to be displayed on both sheets. I can use

```
=('Sheet_name'!A1)
```

to create a one-way dependency. However, is it possible to create a table that updates both ways? Changes in either sheet should appear in both sheets.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a practical question about a Web app.

Answer (score 1):

That is just not possible. Google Sheets can't handle such paradox, eg. to reference the reference of reference with itself.